# How to select specific class item from list?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

how can I select specific class item from a list? I want to bind only Name in the label.

mycountry.cs

```
public class mycountry{

private string Id;
private string name;
private string capital;
private string majorcity;


public string ID { get{return Id;} set{Id = value;}}
public string Name { get{return name;} set{name = value;}}
public string Capital { get{return capital;} set{capital = value;}}
public string Majorcity { get{return majorcity;} set{majorcity = value;}}
}
```

mycountrypage.xaml.cs

```
List<mycountry> c;
c =  DB.GetCountry(); 

ListView list = new ListView{
ItemsSource = c,
ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>{ 
Label name = new Label(); name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, c.?)}
}
```

Comment: @mybirthname thank you. Now I can select the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the existing TextCell type for simple cells

```
list.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
list.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Name");
```

Comment: what if I have another attribute in mycountry called private MyFlag flag; how can I select item from that class. list.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, c.MyFlag.?);

Comment: TextCell also has a DetailTextProperty you can use, or refer to the docs for other bindable props